# React iterate recursively through nested objects

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

i'm trying to iterate recursively over nested objects to get the key and the value.

My data structure is:

```
  {         
    "id": 8743077530231325861,
    "name": "Name of XYZ",
    "key X": 0,
    "key Y": {
      "details": {
        "value": {
          "up": 5,
          "down": 3
        },
        "path": "xyz"
      },
      "key Z": {
        "value": 1,
        "path": "abc"
      }
    },
    "createdTimestamp": 1554446703000
  }
```

and my function is:

```
  recursion = (item, keyString) => {
    if(isObject(item)){
      Object.keys(item).map((key) => {
        return this.recursion(item[key], keyString+`.${key}`)
      })
    }else{
      return {item, keyString}
    }
  }
```

and i call it by:

```
Object.keys(data).map(key =>{
   console.log(this.recursion(data[key], key))
})
```

My problem is that keys which are objects are always undefined.
I know thats because they need to iterate an other time and the output is faster then the function. When i print out the values at the end of the recursion function instead of returning them, they are not undefined.

At the end i want for every key all the deepest values and "paths". For Example

```
8743077530231325861,"id"
Name of XYZ,"name"
0, "keyX"
5, "keyY.details.value.up"
...
```

I already tried to use await / async but i cant manage to get all values

would be nice if someone have a hint for me

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: You are not returning anything in `if(isObject(item)){ ... }`. Update `Object.keys(item).map` to `return Object.keys(item).map` and it should work

Comment: @MaheerAli i want to get the deepest nested item and the path. First Ouput = 8743077530231326000, id, Second: Name of XYZ, name, Thrid: 5, keyY.details.value.up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result of mapping.

```js
const
    isObject = v => v && typeof v === 'object',
    recursion = (item, path = '') => isObject(item)
        ? Object
            .keys(item)
            .flatMap(k => recursion(item[k], path + (path && '.') + k))
        : { item, path };

var data = { id: 8743077530231326000, name: "Name of XYZ", "key X": 0, "key Y": { details: { value: { up: 5, down: 3 }, path: "xyz" }, "key Z": { value: 1, path: "abc" } }, createdTimestamp: 1554446703000 },
    result = recursion(data);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: but this way its returning the Object as Arrays. I want to call for every key in the Object again the recursion to just print out the deepest item + key pair. Like:

5, keyY.details.value.up, 3, keyY.details.value.down etc

Comment: please add the wanted result to the question. btw, the question does not state that the deepest object is needed. what about if you have more than one?

Comment: i added the wanted result